# Apache virtualhosts won't run on OSX (Chrome: "Could not find "folder")

Tags: php, macos, apache, hosts

I'm just learning about web development and am already struggling :) with just the basics set-up.

I am on a MacBook Air OSX 10.8.2
XAMPP 1.8.3-2
Firefox, Chrome, Safari, all the latest versions.

Everything works when using htdocs folder to develop but this way I can only have one site (and one index.php file which loads on "localhost" no?).

I decided to change the directory where Apache looks for files and followed the instructions. I edited httpd.conf file, then httpd-vhosts.conf file and finally hosts. Restarted apache, checked that it's config file that it has a user (daemon) so that should not be the issue.

Started Chrome, wrote: localhost - nothing. "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost"
Then http://testsite.local - "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost"

Any idea what went wrong?
Many thanks!

httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/EdChigliak/Websites"
<Directory "/Users/EdChigliak/Websites">
```

httpd-vhosts.conf (commented out 2 dummy hosts and added my custom one)

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
# ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
# DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
# ServerName dummy-host.example.com
# ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
# ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
# CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>
#localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# My custom host
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName probniphp.local
DocumentRoot "/Users/EdChigliak/Websites/probniphp"
<Directory "/Users/EdChigliak/Websites/probniphp">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow From All
</Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you add `probniphp.local` and `localhost` to ypur hosts file? (/etc/hosts)

Comment: Yep! Here it is: #Virtual Hosts
127.0.0.1 probniphp.local

Answer (score 0):

If your entry in your hosts file is literally

```
#Virtual Hosts 127.0.0.1 probniphp.local
```

Then it is not working because you have commented out that line by using the #.

Write it like this instead:

```
#Virtual Hosts
127.0.0.1 probniphp.local
```

So you comment line now is "#Virtual Hosts" and your IP is on an uncommented line that can be properly run.